# Python determine if HTTPConnection failed to connect

Tags: python, http, httpconnection, httplib

In Python, how I can determine if `HTTPConnection` failed to connect to server, for example, by bad server address?

```
import httplib
import sys
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print 'Usage: server'
    quit()
con = httplib.HTTPConnection(argv[1]) # how I can determine if this fails?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this after instantiating the object `con.connect()`.

If the connection is unable to be made, this call will throw an exception.

Example:

```
>>> import httplib
>>> con = httplib.HTTPConnection('127.0.0.1')
>>> con.connect()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 772, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding `try()` and `except()` statements.